# Does Silverlight have a VirtualizingStackPanel?

Tags: silverlight, virtualizingstackpanel

Does Silverlight have a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx)?
If there is no built in type are there any third party controls that implement this?

Comment: Can you explain (or link) to what a VirtualizingStackPanel is?

Comment: Not sure if anybody out there is monitoring this thread, but if you could at least consider upvoting the Silverlight 3 answer, it'd get this old question off of the Unanswered section of the Silverlight tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel(VS.95).aspx) (MSDN Library) was added with the release of Silverlight 3.